# How can I call hook calls from react class bases components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use functions like **useMediaQuery** in class based components.
How can I make achieve this ?

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { withStyles ,withTheme ,withMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core'

class Main extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const { children ,classes,theme} = this.props;
        const isDesktop = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('lg'),{
            defaultMatches :true
        });
        return (
        <div className ={clsx({
            [classes.root] : true,
            [classes.shiftContent] : isDesktop
        })}>
             <main>
                {children}
            </main>
        </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you could read this article https://reacttraining.com/blog/using-hooks-in-classes/

Comment: @Satif thanks for the information but I could not able to refactor my class as mentioned in above article.

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `useMediaQuery` and the rest of the logic in another component:

```
const WithClasses = ({ children, theme, classes }) => {
  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("lg"), {
    defaultMatches: true
  });
  return (
    <div
      className={clsx({
        [classes.root]: true,
        [classes.shiftContent]: isDesktop
      })}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then use it in your layout like this:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children, classes, theme } = this.props;
    return (
      <WithClasses theme={theme} classes={classes}>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </WithClasses>
    );
  }
}
```